# Why does this child node not get removed in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to remove the event node once it expires and remove all it's children
[image of the event node before getting removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32XzX.png)

the problem is when the time passes and i delete the event node all it's children get removed except this child

[image of the event node after getting removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Illih.png)

source code

```
exports.removeOldEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const eventsRef = admin.database().ref('events')
eventsRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        child.forEach((child) => {
            if (1000*Number(child.val()['endDate']) <= new Date().getTime()) {
                child.ref.set(null)
          }
        })
    })
})
return res.status(200).end()
})
```

Comment: You might want to watch my video series on dealing with promises in Cloud Functions.  If you don't handle promises correctly, many things will appear to not work.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thank you!! i will watch the videos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call several time the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method, which returns a promise, you should use `Promise.all()` in order to wait all the promises resolve before sending back the response.

The following adaptation of your code should work (not tested however):

```
exports.removeOldEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   const eventsRef = admin.database().ref('events')

   eventsRef.once('value')
   .then((snapshot) => {
      const promises = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          child.forEach((child) => {
              if (1000*Number(child.val().endDate) <= new Date().getTime()) {
                  promises.push(child.ref.set(null));
              }
          });
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
   })
   .then(results => {
      const responseObj = {response: 'success'};
      res.send(responseObj);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
   })
});
```

Comment: I used the code and it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. It always removes everything successfully but only the nested child "coordinate" stays sometimes?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. You say "It **always** removes **everything** successfully" and you say "the nested child "coordinate" **stays sometimes**". These two parts of your sentence are in opposition...

Comment: I'm sorry I meant it always removes everything successfully except the "coordinate child. that child sometimes gets removed with the other children and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: for example: I create an event and the remove function gets run and the node gets removed and everything underneath it gets removed too, but I create another event and everything gets removed except the nested child "coordinate" it remains this time.

Comment: Normally all the child elements should be deleted, as explained in the `set()` doc: "Passing null for the new value is equivalent to calling remove(); namely, all data at this location and all child locations will be deleted.". However I've updated the answer with some corrections. Can you try it again?

Comment: Ok I got the problem now, there wasn't an issue with your code all along. The problem is that i pushed the coordinates to the database inside an observe function so whenever the app is open it would push the coordinates to the database. the reason it sometimes "removed" or didn't "remove" depended on wether the app was open.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for helping!! now I will switch the code into queries to see which events are expired instead of going through all events and checking. If you could turn the code into queries I would so much appreciate it. sorry for being annoying.

Comment: I would suggest you give a try, it is not difficult! :-) Have a look a the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data, you should use `starAt()` or `endAt()`. And then you just call `query.once()`, exactly like you do with `eventsRef.once()`.

Comment: FYI, to try and find the correct query you don't need to do it in the Cloud Function. You can very well set up a simple HTML page that makes some queries to your database. It might be faster that trying several versions of the Cloud Function.

Comment: @mbm Hi, did you give try? Was it successful?